# Showing a hidden div with jquery and moving to the top of the page

Tags: jquery

I have a div on my page which is hidden on load.
Using Jquery I want to display the hidden div and hide the open div. This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// hides the slickbox as soon as the DOM is ready
$('#details').hide();

// shows the slickbox on clicking the noted link  
$('#proceed').click(function () {
    $('#details').show('slow');
    $('#contColL').hide('slow');
    $('#contColR').hide('slow');
    $('#intro').hide('slow');
    return false;
});

$('#reviewPlate').click(function () {
    $('#details').hide('slow');
    $('#contColL').show('slow');
    $('#contColR').show('slow');
    $('#intro').show('slow');
    return false;
});             
</script>
```

This works OK but I cant get the new page to display from the top. Instead it displays from the named div - details.
How can I get the newly displayed page to display from the top?

Comment: can you show us an example in jsfiddle?

Comment: if you want to just scroll to the top of your page do this: $('body').scrollTop(0) if you are using jquery. OR element.scrollTop if you want plain javascript.References: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollTop http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Comment: $('body').css({scrollTo:"50px"})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add a line to scroll your page to top in the end of the method:

```
window.scrollTo(0,0)
```

Or if you want to animate scroll, you animated scroll top:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "0px" }, 500);
```

Where `500` is the duration of the animation.

Then your code will look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// hides the slickbox as soon as the DOM is ready
$('#details').hide();

// shows the slickbox on clicking the noted link  
$('#proceed').click(function () {
    $('#details').show('slow');
    $('#contColL').hide('slow');
    $('#contColR').hide('slow');
    $('#intro').hide('slow');
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "0px" }, 500);
    return false;
});

$('#reviewPlate').click(function () {
    $('#details').hide('slow');
    $('#contColL').show('slow');
    $('#contColR').show('slow');
    $('#intro').show('slow');
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "0px" }, 500);
    return false;
});             
</script>
```